# Return the undefined when I using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
            var allA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for(var i=0;i<allA.length;i++){
                allA[i].onclick=function(){     
                alert("Are you sure to delect the "+ 
                this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML+"?");
                tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
                return false;}
}
};
</script>
<body>
           <tr id="Tlist">
                <th>A</th>
                <the>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <td><a href="javascript">Select</a></td>
            </tr>
</body>
```

The above code is a part of the HTML file, when I click the Select, I used parenNode.ParenNode to get the Tlist, and use firstChild to get the A, if the code without innerHTML, it will show me the whole Twist, so I think I did a right thing to get the Tlist. However, when I used innerHTML to try to get the text inside the first , that shows me undefined.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should generally use `firstElementChild` so you skip over text nodes.

Comment: @hev1 OK, I posted the code

Comment: Is there a `<table>` around the `<tr>`? You can use [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to provide an executable example.

Comment: @Barmar OH, Cool, it works, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `firstElementChild` rather than `firstChild`. `firstChild` will return a text node, in this case the whitespace before the first `<th>`. Using `firstElementChild` skips over text nodes.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var allA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < allA.length; i++) {
    allA[i].onclick = function() {
      var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
      alert("Are you sure to delect the " +
        tr.firstElementChild.innerHTML + "?");
      tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="Tlist">
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```